# How to display 24 hour counter once button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

Once my button is pressed I would like to disable my button for 24 hours and displaying a countdown on a label display a countdown until the button will be active again.

I have saved the waiting date and compared it to current date but I am not sure how to display the countdown of how much time is left in hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
let todaysDate = Date()

func set24HrTimer() {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let newDate = Date(timeInterval: 86400, since: currentDate as Date)

    UserDefaults.standard.set(newDate, forKey: "waitingDate")
    print("24 hours started")

    //disable the button

}


if let waitingDate:Date = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "waitingDate") as? Date {
        if (todaysDate.compare(waitingDate as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending) {
            print("show button")

        }
        else {
            print("hide button")

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use Date instead of the older NSDate, Date is the proper swift class.

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)` or `setValue(_:forKey:)` with `UserDefaults`. Use the proper API. And as already stated, do not use `NSDate`, use `Date`.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, one is to use a [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add following code to create time countdown.

First add two variable ass follow:

```
fileprivate var timeWorking : Bool = false  // To check is timer already scheduled
var timer:Timer?  // Instance of timer
```

Then add following code which will calculate remaining hour, minute and second.

```
func timeLeftExtended(date:Date) ->NSAttributedString{

    let cal = Calendar.current
    let now = Date()
    let calendarUnits:NSCalendar.Unit = [NSCalendar.Unit.hour, NSCalendar.Unit.minute, NSCalendar.Unit.second]
    let components = (cal as NSCalendar).components(calendarUnits, from: now, to: date, options: [])

    let fullCountDownStr = "\(components.hour!.description)h " + "\(components.minute!.description)m " + "\(components.second!.description)s "

    let mutableStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullCountDownStr, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])

    for (index, char) in mutableStr.string.enumerated()
    {
        if(char == "h" || char == "m" || char == "s")
        {
            mutableStr.removeAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
            mutableStr.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightGray], range: NSMakeRange(index, 1))
        }
    }

    return mutableStr
}
```

Next, add code which is `scheduledTimer` if not `scheduled`.

```
func setupTimer()
{
    if(!timeWorking)
    {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateCountDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.timeWorking = true
    }
}
```

Add code to display count down in label.

```
@objc func updateCountDown()
{
    if let waitingDate = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "waitingDate") as? Date {

        self.labelCountDown.attributedText = self.timeLeftExtended(date: waitingDate)

    } else {
        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 24, to: Date())
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newDate, forKey: "waitingDate")
        self.labelCountDown.attributedText = self.timeLeftExtended(date: newDate!)
    }
}
```

Call `setupTimer()` method to continue timer.

**Output:**

[image: Countdown Timer]